PHP: Is feof() always required for fread()?
In PHP feof() tests for the end of file, but the documentation says that fread() would stop once the end of file is reached:

fread() reads up to length bytes from the file pointer referenced by
stream. Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is
met: [...] EOF (end of file) is reached [...]
Source: PHP Documentation, fread(), https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

The documentation also states that it would return false in case of failure:

Returns the read string or false on failure.

In this example the break is triggered because fread() would return an empty string (but not false!) once the end of file is reached, so it works as intended:
$content = null;
$handle = fopen('FILE.txt', 'rb');

while (true) {
    $buffer = fread(resource: $handle, length: 32);
    
    if (!$buffer) {
        break;
    }
    
    $content .= $buffer;
}

fclose($handle);

However, almost all examples are different: They seem to always use feof() together with fread():
$content = null;
$handle = fopen('FILE.txt', 'rb');
    
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $content .= fread(resource: $handle, length: 32);
}
    
fclose($handle);

Why is that? Is relying on fread() unsafe? When I wrote my code my initial idea was just this:
$content = null;
$handle = fopen('FILE.txt', 'rb');
    
while ($buffer = fread(resource: $handle, length: 32)) {
    $content .= $buffer;
}
    
fclose($handle);


That feof() example is wrong. The problem is that the EOF indicator isn't set until after you try to read at the end of the file. You're checking before the last read.

The feof() example is actually Example #3 Remote fread() examples from the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

That example is also wrong, and so are the examples in the feof() documentation.  See the user comments in the latter, e.g. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php#67261

The main use of feof() is distinguishing EOF from the reading function returning false due to an error.

But is then my example (the very first and last code) right? I don't see why feof() is required at all. If there is an error and feof() would return false, I could use exactly that to detect if there was an error or just EOF was reached.

It's not required at all. See the answers to the linked question. The normal idiom is while ($line = fgets($fp)) or while ($buffer = fread($handle, $length))

if you want the entire file, just use $content = file_get_contents($filename);

Strange. Thanks for clarifying.
